# best crossover for route optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, crossover

I was checking on crossover techniques for route optimization and have gone through few of thgem as mentioned below

```
1 - single point crossover
2 - two point crossover
3 - uniform crossover
```

In single point crossover, we generally swap one variable from each parent and get the child. The same with two point crossover where we swap two variables from two parents .

In my problems, the parents length's are not same, for example `p1: ['a','b','c'] and p2:['v','n','m','h','k']` . As we the length of both parents are not same, I was able to use single point crossover based on the even and odd technique.

Now I want to use the uniform crossover with masking and finding it difficult to use with different lengths.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What length are the offspring to be, if they are to be the same length of the parents then you could just do a normal uniform order. For example

```
 [a,b,c] = p1
 [v,n,m,h,k] = p2
 [0,0,1,0,1] = mask (this should be random)

 [v,n,c] = o1
 [a,b,m,h,k] = o2
```

You could even randomly place where the smaller one sits on the mask for example:

```
 [-,-,v,n,c]
 [a,b,m,h,k]
```

so offspring would be

```
 [v,h,c] 
 [a,b,m,n,k]
```